# Limit inventory groups using Ansible plugin in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins pipeline job, in which I have multiple stages that target a specific inventory. The thing is, on one of the stages I have to target just two groups (`grp_a`, `grp_b`) from the inventory. With `ansible-playbook` command I can use `--limit` or `-l` but I don't know how to use this in jenkins pipeline `ansiblePlaybook`, here is my example :

```
stage ("Stuff"){  
  steps {
    println "###########################   +Install Stuff   ###########################"
    ansiblePlaybook becomeUser: 'root', installation: 'Ansible', inventory: 'hosts/my_file/hosts', playbook: 'main.yml', extraVars: [ Var_1: "1", var_2: "2"]
  }
}
```

And here is an exemple of my inventory :

```
[grp_1]
m_1
m_2
m_3
[grp_2]
m_2
m_4
[grp_3]
m_1
m_2
m_5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit` option of `ansiblePlaybook` like so,

```
stage ("Stuff"){
  steps {
    ansiblePlaybook ..., limit: "grp_a:grp_b", ...
  }
}
```